# Push to client using DLNA

Tags: c#

Windows Media Player has a play to feature that can send video files to a client device which start playing.  I was wondering if anyone has a starting point to replicate this feature in c#?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to push a video to a DMR client (Digital Media Renderer), then you need to implement UPNP / DLNA control point (DMC) and also you need to have a Digital Media Server (DMS) which host that video file.
For a starting point in C# you can take a look at UPNP / DLNA tools and libraries developed by Intel at following link,

http://opentools.homeip.net/dev-tools-for-upnp

I hope it helps.